# in-Built linux application with the kernel image or boot.img

Tags: c, makefile, linux-kernel

how to make an application in built(like top, vi , etc ) so that they can be put inside the /system/bin automatically on flashing the kernel and can be accessed from the command prompt.
I tried modifying the Makefile for the my application by looking at the example of top utility but could not find it under `/system/bin .`

I am not sure if I have included the sources of the file in the Makefile correctly.

Comment: Is this for an embedded system or just on a PC?

Comment: target is embedded device

Answer (score 1):

You need to start with something that the manufacturer provided.  Presumably it's a devKit or something.  Most modern dev kits ship with either a MFG provided development environment, kernel, sources, etc.  Many are based on Yocto Linux.

You can't just compile a binary locally on your PC with whatever version of GCC you have and have it work on an embedded environment.  Chances are it's a different architecture (ARM or Freescale or something). There are ways to cross-compile but is some setup involved.  Read about cross compiling here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler

There are development and packaging environments that have been developed by the community but it's not for the faint of heart. In short, start reading: https://www.yoctoproject.org/